# airflow not picking up dags from kubernetes persistentvolume

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I'm trying to follow [this](https://gitlab.com/usama.kaleem88/kubernetes-airflow) tutorial but the last part doesn't work for me. No dags are being shown on airflow.

I check the logs of the pods. scheduler and worker are respectively as follows

**SCHEDULER**

```
*** executing Airflow initdb...
DB: postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:***@airflow-postgresql:5432/airflow
[2020-06-17 18:33:57,698] {db.py:378} INFO - Creating tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
Done.
*** adding Airflow variables...
0 of 0 variables successfully updated.
*** adding Airflow pools...
0 of 0 pool(s) successfully updated.

╒════════╤═════════╤═══════════════╕
│ Pool   │ Slots   │ Description   │
╞════════╪═════════╪═══════════════╡
╘════════╧═════════╧═══════════════╛
*** running scheduler...
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
[2020-06-17 18:34:12,477] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2020-06-17 18:34:12,485] {scheduler_job.py:1346} INFO - Starting the scheduler
[2020-06-17 18:34:12,485] {scheduler_job.py:1354} INFO - Running execute loop for -1 seconds
[2020-06-17 18:34:12,486] {scheduler_job.py:1355} INFO - Processing each file at most -1 times
[2020-06-17 18:34:12,486] {scheduler_job.py:1358} INFO - Searching for files in /opt/airflow/dags
[2020-06-17 18:34:12,486] {scheduler_job.py:1360} INFO - There are 0 files in /opt/airflow/dags
[2020-06-17 18:34:12,487] {scheduler_job.py:1411} INFO - Resetting orphaned tasks for active dag runs
[2020-06-17 18:34:12,503] {dag_processing.py:556} INFO - Launched DagFileProcessorManager with pid: 44
[2020-06-17 18:34:12,506] {settings.py:54} INFO - Configured default timezone <Timezone [UTC]>
```

**WORKER**

```
*** running scheduler...
[2020-06-17 18:34:05,202] {cli_action_loggers.py:107} WARNING - Failed to log action with (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "airflow-postgresql" to address: Name or service not known

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
[2020-06-17 18:34:07,170: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://:**@airflow-redis-master:6379/1
[2020-06-17 18:34:07,218: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2020-06-17 18:34:08,344: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2020-06-17 18:34:08,385: INFO/MainProcess] celery@airflow-worker-0 ready.
Starting flask
 * Serving Flask app "airflow.bin.cli" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
[2020-06-17 18:34:09,179] {_internal.py:122} INFO -  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8793/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2020-06-17 18:34:12,779: INFO/MainProcess] Events of group {task} enabled by remote.
```

I'm new with airflow and Kubernetes. What's wrong here. why it isn't picking the volume and dags?

Comment: I ran the tutorial you linked and I couldn't find the issue you are experiencing. Outputs from scheduler were different too. Scheduler was looking in another directory for dags. Have you changed anything while deploying? Can you tell where are you trying to run it? Is it `minikube`, `kubeadm cluster`, managed solution like `GKE` or `EKS`?

Comment: locally, tried both minikube and microk8s. now using microk8s. Didn't do anything, just installed microk8s, helm, and ran the command.

Comment: what path did you set up for the dags dir? it's your absolute local path right, ending with /dags?
Also, could you explain to me how is airflow picking up this path which give as a volume?

Comment: Yes. You are right with the path. It must be an absolute path ending with `/dags`. Airflow is picking it up from the Helm chart and the `airflow.yaml` values file. I've tried to use the `microk8s` but I stumbled on the same issue as yours. You cannot see the files as the Helm chart is not creating mount point with the `airflow-pvc` to the folder responsible for storing `dags`.  Coming back to my first comment I used `docker-desktop` and haven't stumbled upon those issues.

Comment: **You cannot see the files as the Helm chart is not creating mount point with the airflow-pvc to the folder responsible for storing dags** how do you know this? is it logged somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you can check the `YAML` definition of a `airflow-scheduler` with the `$ kubectl get airflow-scheduler-name -o yaml` also you can get this information running the Helm chart in `--debug --dry-run mode` like this: `$  helm upgrade --install --force --recreate-pods airflow --values airflow.yml stable/airflow --dry-run --debug`. You will see lack of `airflow-pvc` in the `volume` definition of an `airflow-scheduler` pod.

Comment: yes, I checked using describe and -o yaml. Don't see the mount which is supposed to be there using the volumes.
Strange, I tried using minikube as well and stumbled into same issue. Do you have MacOS or Windows?

Comment: Please try to use MacOS for this if possible.